# Service to service connection using RabbitMQ in nestjs

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

```
What I am looking for: a way to connect service to service connection through RabbitmMQ, where I have implemented a microservice in both services which means no port is there.
```

Gateway to service connection I have done. but the service-to-service connection without a port is my challenge.

```
anyone has an idea or some reference on how to implement this.
```

Comment: please provide more details.

Comment: as I explained, I want to make a connection between service to service with RabbitMQ message protocol.

Comment: Have you followed NestJs microservice official documentation? And if you did, please show us what you have tried.